# malloc in for loop

Tags: c, memory-management

i have a question... lets say i have the following part of code :

```
int *a,*a1,*a2;
for (i=1; i<=2; i++) {
    a=malloc(sizeof(int));
    if (i==1) a1=a;
    else if (i==2) a2=a;
}
*a1=5;
*a2=4;
```

so my question is 
if i use printf to print a1 and a2 the variable a1 is gonna to have the value 5 and the a2 the value 4 ? so if i use malloc to allocate memory and a points in that memory space and use again malloc to allocate memory then a points to a different part of memory but the first one part of memory still exist ? or if i use malloc with a again it will erase the first part of memory and it will write a new part of memory

Comment: You probably want `==` in `if` conditions.

Comment: what was the practical use again??^^

Comment: if u want to print 5 and 4, u have to print deferenced a1 and a2 respectively. 
and You have never initialized *a. Undefined behaviours.

Comment: my problem is the use of malloc and not the printing of a1 and a2 ...i gave them as example

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Each call to `malloc` returns a pointer to different memory, until you call `free` to release that memory.

Comment: nope, the behaviour of malloc is platform-defined, how you can say that ?

Comment: so if i use malloc to a pointer named a 2 times the part of memory created first will not be erased so if i use another pointer to oint it i will have two memory spaces at the end right ?

Comment: @user1809300 the best answer to your question is: malloc is unsafe, not-portable, and you should avoid using that function, consider adopting C++ as your major language or document your on malloc alternatives and safer practices

Comment: @user1809300: Essentially, yes. Note that `malloc` does not create memory, and it does not erase memory. `malloc` merely manages memory. If it needs more memory, it will request it from the operating system. It maintains its own records about what memory is available. When you call `malloc`, it makes whatever changes it needs in its records and returns a pointer to space that is set aside just for your use. (Or, if it cannot provide the memory, it will return NULL.) It will not use that space for anything else. When you call `free`, it adjusts records to show that the space may be reused.

Comment: @user1809300: `malloc` is portable and is defined by the C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil you just said that malloc works at OS level, now you are saying that is **defined** by the standard, pick one not two. Malloc() is not defined by the standard, by the way, your answer is incorrect and if not you simply have to provide the paragraph where malloc is **defined** in the standard as proof of what you are writing.

Comment: @user1797612: (1) I did not say `malloc` works at the OS level. I said it makes requests of the operating system. (2) The standard defines behavior, not implementation. (3) `malloc` is specified in C 2011 7.22.3.4, in association with the surrounding clauses.

Comment: **I doubt if this really is correct answer.** Why OP selected it? for vote-count?

Comment: @user1797612: You missed an excellent opportunity to remain silent. Please consider deleting your misguided, and misguiding, comments.

Answer (score 3):

> if i use printf to print a1 and a2 the variable a1 is gonna to have the value 5 and the a2 the value 4 ?

Erm... no.

`a1` (being of type `int *`, i.e. *pointer* to integer) will contain the *address* resulting from the first call to `malloc()`.

`a2` (and `a`), being also of pointer type, will contain the *address* resulting from the *second* call to `malloc()`.

The *address* in `a1` will point to an integer, to which you assigned the value 5.

The *address* in `a2` (and `a`) will point to an integer, to which you assigned the value 4.

Both of those integers will remain allocated until you release them by calling `free()` on their address. **Be careful**: After you called e.g. `free( a2 )`, the integer is no longer allocated. Calling `free()` again on the same address (e.g. via `free( a )`, or by calling `free( a2 )` a second time) will result in undefined behaviour (i.e., if you are lucky, your program will crash).

A pointer is an *address value*. It seems this is where your confusion comes from: It isn't identical to the thing it points to.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: Yes, I am sure about my first statement. `a1` contains the **address** of the value, not the value itself. To get at the value (5), you have to **dereference** the pointer (`*a1`), like your linked code does in the assignment as well as the `printf()` statement.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im: Try this: `printf( "a1 = %d\n", a1 );`. Surprised?

Comment: I know that. But I thought OP meant `*a1` by `a1`. Its not very uncommon. +1 to you. I think this should be the correct answer than the selected one.

Comment: @DevSolar -- IANAL, but I think passing a pointer value to printf when it expects an integer value (per `%d`) is UB (yes, I understand you were making a point to explain to @shiplu).

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps: Yes, strictly speaking you should use `%p` for pointer arguments. And yes, I consciously ignored that to make the point. Unless `sizeof( int ) != sizeof( void * )`, though, it might be UB, but it would work nevertheless. (Not that I don't usually crucify people for being sloppy like that, myself. ;-) )

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to your question is yes. Malloc'ing will give you a memory location with (at least) the specified size (if available). It does not free any memory, only gives you more (use `free()` to free malloc'ed memory).

The fact that you are using some temporary variable `a` has no significance. At the end of this loop `a == a2 != a1`

Answer (score 0):

> if i use printf to print a1 and a2 the variable a1 is gonna to have the value 5 and the a2 the value 4 ?

Yes, you are correct. It is a bit strange question, though, because it is easier to try and see than to ask.

> so if i use malloc to allocate memory and a points in that memory space and use again malloc to allocate memory then a points to a different part of memory but the first one part of memory still exist ?

That is correct. `malloc()` allocates memory that "exists" until you free it using `free()`, or do a `realloc()` that could possibly move your data to a different memory and release the old memory location. I'd recommend you read some documentation about it. The [manual page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/malloc.3.html) at least.

Also, your code has errors. You use assignment instead of comparison and variable `i` is not defined. Here is a corrected version with a `printf()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int *a,*a1,*a2;
    int i;

    for (i=1; i<=2; i++) {
        a = malloc(sizeof(int));
        if (i==1)
            a1 = a;
        else if (i==2)
            a2 = a;
    }
    *a1=5;
    *a2=4;

    printf("a1=%d, a2=%d\n", *a1, *a2);

    free(a1);
    free(a2);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Hope it helps. Good Luck!